# Mongodb / Mongoose, can only update limited (6) number of documents before it freezes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a angular app using the MEAN stack. I have the following code in my express app:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var username = req.user.username;
  var items = req.body.items;
  if (items) {
    items = JSON.parse(items);
  } else {
    return
  }
  if (!username) {
    res.status(401).send('There is no username');
    return
  }
  User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).send('No user with that username');
    }
    if (typeof items === 'number') {
      console.log('yes');
      user.update({$push: {cart: items}}, {}, function (err, user, ob) {
        console.log('update', err, user, ob);
      });
    } else {
      user.update({$pushAll: {cart: items}}, {}, function (err, user, ob) {
        console.log('update', err, user, ob);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

On the angular side, whenever I try to make more than 6 push (update) requests consecutively, the node program freezes, (nothing updates, no post requests are logged), for a minutes or two, then the post requests are received. Is there some reason this is happening? When node freezes up nothing works (it serves no requests) but doesn't crash.

Here is an example of the express log:

```
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
// Very long pause
POST /addproduct - - ms - -
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
POST /addproduct - - ms - -
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
POST /addproduct - - ms - -
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
POST /addproduct - - ms - -
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
POST /addproduct - - ms - -
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
POST /addproduct - - ms - -
yes
update null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.js, the maximum amout of opened socket is five (Before version 0.12, released this friday)...
Here, you don't seem to close the request in case of update...
Maybe you're firsts requests needs to go to timeout before you can accept the next ones ?

just add a res.status(200).end() in this case ? (Not sure of the syntax)
If this doesn't work, let me know.